# Is there a way to parse JSON with java?

Tags: java, json

Here is what I have so far:

```
 public Bitmap getAlbumCover(Context context, String song, String artist) {
    this.context = context;
    song = song.replace(" ", "%20");
    artist = artist.replace(" ", "%20");

    try {
        conn = new URL("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track" + song + ":%20artist:" + artist + "&type=track)").openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (conn != null)
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (reader != null) {
        // Read Server Response
        String line2 = null;
        try {
            while ((line2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line2);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            json = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        try {
            array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // take each value from the json array separately

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

The JSON I am using is located here: 
     https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:Ready%20To%20Fall%20artist:rise%20against%20&type=track

I am trying to get the image url located in the images array and the preview_track url located in items.

Comment: You already have `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);` so this should answer your question, doesn't it? Just expand on that to extract the value you need.

Comment: I would recommend Jackson databind for parsing JSON with Java - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/

Comment: Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I use Jackson library to parse JSON to java opbject.

if you create your java object with the same structure as JSON this can be done using this:

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, YourClass.class);
```

So your OBJECT will have tracks and then tracks will have object album and album will have object other details. Just structure it as the JSON is and you are there.